# Socket.IO query object not defined in authorization data

Tags: node.js, angularjs, socket.io

I am trying to do token-based URL authentication with socket.io (version 1.0+) and I am unable to read the query object from the following:

```
//server code snippet

io.set('authorization', function (data, accept){
  console.log(data.query); //prints undefined
  //authentication logic...
});

//client code snippet

angular.module('app')
.factory('socket', function ($rootScope){
    var socketProvider = 'http://localhost:3000';
    var token = 'testtoken';
    var socket = io.connect(socketProvider, {'query': 'token=' + token});
    //more factory code for websocket handling...
});
```

The socket connects successfully and I am able to access the "protected" query object using **data._query**, but I do not want to use it this way because it is dirty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [migration guide](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/#authentication-differences):

> The old `io.set()` and `io.get()` methods are deprecated and only supported for backwards compatibility.

Instead, you may use something like:

```
io.use(function(socket, next) {
    if (socket.handshake.query.token === 'Your valid token') {
        next();
    } else {
        next(new Error('Your error message for the client'));
    }
});
```